# Place Bar Charts at specific locations

Tags: charts, flutter

I'm trying to add an annotation to a bar chart in flutter. But I'm having a hard time setting the annotation's start and end positions to specific numbers other than the labels of my bar chart.

So, here're the main questions:
Does the bar chart need to have 'String' as the domain values (return of domainFn)?
And,
assuming my bar chart labels are all integers values (converted to Strings), how can I specify a double, say, 1.5, as the place where the annotation is placed?